# Connecting TV decoder to proprietary modem via WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, tv

(See below for edits after ***)

I'm based in France where Orange is my ISP. I use the Orange "Livebox 4" modem, which I believe is fairly standard, and have also leased a Orange TV decoder which is designed to work with the Livebox. When connected directly together, either via the Livebox WiFi network or ethernet cable, the TV decoder works fine and I can access TV.

At the same time, I have set up a WiFi Mesh network throughout my house (which is big with thick stone walls, requiring something more than just a single repeater or extender; and power line technology doesn't work because there are multiple circuits) using ASUS ZenWiFi AX. The router is plugged into the Livebox in its standard wireless router mode, and I have 3 other nodes connected via WiFi to form the mesh. The network has a different name from the Livebox network.

Now when I try to connect the TV decoder through the Mesh network (directly to a node through a cable or through WiFi) the connection fails.

Does anyone have any guidance on how to set this up? Note the ZenWiFi setup app offers several modes of operation, including Access Point, Repeater Mode, and Media Bridge. One thing I tried was to change it to Access Point and give the network the same name and password as the Livebox network. I got farther to the Orange TV system menu, but still couldn't get access to the TV channels. From what I've read here and there, I should also turn off the DHCP server on the ZenWiFi router, but I haven't tried that yet. Then I'm not sure if I would need to set the IP addresses of the router (and the nodes?) manually or not. I'm afraid of going down a deep rabbit hole.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**** Addendum ****

Thanks for your help!

I've made some progress, I think, though I'm not quite there. I decided to try configuring the Mesh router as an Access Point, still connected via cable to the Livebox.

- First I changed the WiFi name and PW of the Livebox WiFi to match the Mesh WiFi, and verified that the decoder was still able to connect to the Livebox WiFi and I could access the TV channels.
- Then I converted the Mesh router to Access point mode, keeping the same WiFi name/PW. I confirmed that all my devices could still connect to the internet via this network, and that the IP addresses of my devices now appeared on the list of IP addresses managed by the Livebox. That says to me that the DHCP server on the Mesh router is now switched off, as it's supposed to be.
- Then I switched off the WiFi signal from the Livebox so the decoder would be forced to connect to the Mesh AP, and restarted the decoder.

This time I got a lot farther in the setup - all the way to the point where it *looked* like I had access, as I could see options to go to TV or select other special programming from Orange (Netflix, etc). That means it "sees" the Livebox. BUT when I tried actually to access any of the TV channels, I got an error that I wasn't allowed to do this. I think the Orange network doesn't recognize the decoder as belonging to my account.

So close!

One question I have, does it matter whether the Mesh router is connected to the Livebox via its WAN or LAN port? To answer your question, here is a schematic of the Access Point setup:

INTERNET --> Livebox DSL Input --> Livebox LAN 1 output --> Mesh Access Point WAN input --> Wifi (Mesh AP) --> Decoder

Before, the schematic that worked was as follows:

INTERNET --> Livebox DSL Input --> WiFi (Livebox) --> Decoder

(in parallel)                  --> Livebox LAN port 1 output --> Mesh Wireless Router WAN input --> Wifi (Mesh)

I hope that helps! Thanks again for your help.

Michael

Answer (score 1):

You should set the ZenWiFi router to one of the following modes, according
to your layout:

- **Access Point mode**: router connects to a wireless router through an Ethernet cable to extend the coverage of wireless signal to other network clients.
- **Repeater Mode**: router wirelessly connects to an existing wireless networks to extend the wireless coverage.

If the DHCP server is not automatically disabled by the above setting,
do it manually.

It should now work with the whole house as one network. You may test connectivity
by `ping` to devices by their IP address.

In case of a problem, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1652372/edit)
your question and add a schema of your network (only routers, the TV decoder,
the TV and their connectors are important).